# django rest framework not return json

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have writen hello word programme and want to return json format data but it does not working. Please look into my code
URL file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from login import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hello_world/$', views.hello_world),
]
```

View file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
# Create your views here.

@api_view()
def hello_world(request, format=None):
    return Response({"message": "Hello, world!"})
```

http://localhost:8000/login/hello_world/ hit a url

get an error

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/hello_world/

rest_framework/api.html
```

i want this data in json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Django Rest Framework to return Json data that are so simple. If you're just returning such form of data use [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects).

```
# views/hello_world.py

from django.http import JsonResponse

def hello_world(request):
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Hello, world!'})
```

On the other hand, if you want to create an API with Django Rest Framework, you should better start with their [tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) and then move on to more advanced techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://localhost:8000/hello_world/ 
based on url patern.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/
The 'r' in front of each regular expression string is optional but recommended. It tells Python that a string is “raw” – that nothing in the string should be escaped

Answer (score 0):

first install djangorestframework
then add 'rest_framework' in Installed app in settings.py
Example:`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    'chat',
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]`
```